# objective c circular reference

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two custom NSObjects which reference each other, as below:

**.h file class 1**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MyChildClass.h"

@interface MyParentClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Name;
@property (nonatomic) MyChildClass *myChild;

@end
```

**.m file class 1:**

```
#import "MyParentClass.h"

@implementation MyParentClass

@end
```

and...

**.h file class 2:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MyParentClass.h"

@interface MyChildClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) MyParentClass *myParent;

@end
```

**.m file class 2:**

```
#import "MyChildClass.h"

@implementation MyChildClass

@end
```

When I try and implement those as below, the project will not build, with the error "Arc Restrictions: Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'int *' is disallowed with ARC"

**View Controller implementation code:**

```
    MyParentClass *newParent = [[MyParentClass alloc] init];
    MyChildClass *newChild = [[MyChildClass alloc] init];

    newParent.Name = @"Johnny";
    newParent.myChild = newChild;

    newChild.myParent = newParent;
```

However, when I nest a second example into single .h/.m files, the project will build:

**Nested .h file:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class MyNestedClass;

@interface MyChildNestedClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) MyNestedClass *myNested;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *ChildName;

@end

@interface MyNestedClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) MyChildNestedClass *myChild;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *ParentName;

@end
```

**Nested .m file:**

```
#import "MyNestedClass.h"

@implementation MyChildNestedClass

@end

@implementation MyNestedClass

@end
```

I guess that by nesting the  objects into a single file, I am somehow tricking ARC and that really I shouldn't be creating these circular references.

Could anyone suggest the correct way of nesting types like this?

What I am trying to achieve, is the following pseudo-scenario: Parent has a property of Child. Child has a property of the parent it is the child of.

Am I finding this difficult because I'm not supposed to do it (circular referencing), or am I missing something glaringly obvious?

Many thanks!

Comment: FYI - You need to be sure that the child's reference to its parent is a `weak` reference. Otherwise you have some unwanted reference cycles.

Answer (score 4):

Do not `#import "MyChildClass.h"` in the parent class' header file, change it to

```
@class MyChildClass
```

and add the `#import` in the source file (.m)

Comment: Neither .h should import the other .h. Both should use forward declarations.